# AngularJs Loading error on popup

Tags: angularjs

Onclick of form button I am calling a page(AngularJs page) to display
  popup. The popup shows with no content .

But when run that page manually it works because the page is loading.

Comment: Can you show us some code ??

Comment: Hi Pravesh,

Please find the code here https://jsfiddle.net/jtwue1zk/1/

Comment: In servicenow tool that the is way we can call another page in popup

Comment: Please add the code in a code black in the question. This makes it easier for the people trying to help you.

Comment: Im trying to add the code here , but it always giving erors to submit , like code alignment . I was unable to submit my question so i posted script over there.